# vue.js child component isn't updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have a parent and a child component. The parent component "invitations" contains multiple child components of "invitation". When I refresh the website all of the invitations are shown on the website, but as soon as I update the invitations array (adding an invitation) it isn't shown on the page even though I can see the array being updated on the vue developer console. I have to refresh the page to see it.

It looks like this when something has been added to the array (updated):
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9iuS.png)

It looks like this when I refresh the page after it has been added to array.

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENTAa.png)

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6hKK.png)

Here are my two components:

**invitations.vue**

```
<template>
<li class="nav-item dropdown" id="invitations">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Invitations <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 20rem" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" 
    id="dropdownMenu">

        <div v-for="invitation in invitations" v-bind:key="invitation.id" v- 
    bind:invitations="invitations">

            <Invitation :invitation="invitation" v-on:accept-invitation="accept" v-on:reject- 
    invitation="reject" v-bind:invitation="invitation"></Invitation>

        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</template>

<script>
import Invitation from "./Invitation";

export default {
    name: "Invitations",
    props: {
        invitations: {
            type: Array,
            default: [],
            required: true
        },
        user: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        accept(team_id) {
            axios.get('/request/accept/' + team_id)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.invitations = this.invitations.filter(invitation => invitation.id)
                });
        },
        reject(team_id) {
            axios.get('/request/reject/' + team_id)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.invitations = this.invitations.filter(invitation => invitation.id)
                });
        },
        handleIncoming(invitation) {
            this.saveNewInvitation(invitation);
            return;
        },
        saveNewInvitation(invitation) {
            this.invitations.push(invitation);
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        Echo.channel('invitations.' + this.user.id)
            .listen('NewInvitation', (e) => {
                this.handleIncoming(e);
            });
    },
    components: {Invitation}
}
</script>
```

**invitation.vue**

```
<template>
<div :id="invitation.id" class="mb-2">
    <a class="ml-4" title="Show team info" style="margin-right: 90px"
       :href="'/team/index/' + invitation.id" v-bind:name="invitation.name">{{invitation.name}}</a>

    <a class="float-right mr-3" href="#" @click="$emit('reject-invitation', invitation.id)">
        <i class="fas fa-times reject" :teamId="invitation.id"></i>
    </a>

    <a class="float-right mr-3" href="#" @click="$emit('accept-invitation', invitation.id)">
        <i class="fas fa-check accept" :teamId="invitation.id"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Invitation",
    props: {
        invitation: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: why do you have `:invitation="invitation" .... v-bind:invitation="invitation"` - since `:invitation` is just shorthand for `v-bind:invitation` - i.e. they are the same thing ... not saying that's the issue though

Comment: I tried to solve it with v-bind but it didn't work. But even without, it doesn't work.

Comment: the props are objects so might need a deep watcher on the child component

Comment: what's this supposed  to do: `this.invitations = this.invitations.filter(invitation => invitation.id)`

Comment: its supposed to remove the invitation from the list when you accepted or rejected the invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% which function it is that you're specifically using to modify an array, but one place where I notice a potential hang-up is in...

```
saveNewInvitation(invitation) {
  this.invitations.push(invitation);
}
```

In the Vue documentation ([link to "Reactivity in Depth -- For Arrays"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)) Vue specifically warns that it will not notice mutations to the underlying array.

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
>
> When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

Although `.push()` may not immediately trigger alarm, when you read the documentation for the push method ([link to MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)), you notice that it is mutating the array, not creating a new one.

> The push() method **adds one or more elements to the end of an array** and returns the new length of the array. [emphasis added]

As seen in this prior Stack Overflow question ([link to discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386264/how-does-the-javascript-array-push-code-work-internally)), the internal workings of the push method only do two things -- change the length, and set an item by index -- which are the only two things Vue **can't** see.

One method that will create a new Array object is `concat()`:

```
saveNewInvitation(invitation) {
  this.invitations = this.invitations.concat(invitation)
}
```

...because, as mentioned in the docs for `concat()` ([link to MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)):

> Return value: A new Array instance.

...which Vue will properly see.